# Using xpath with SimpleXMLElement returning blank result?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

XML:

```
<A>
  <B type="source">
    <C>
      <D>
        <E ref="description">my_desc</E>
        <E>Some other E</E>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

PHP:

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('URL.xml', null, true);
$path = $doc->xpath('A/B[@type="source"]/C/D/E[@ref="description"]');
var_dump ($path);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
)
```

Ultimately, I am trying to get the inner value of `<E>` with a `ref="description"`. What am I doing wrong? Following guide from: http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath

Comment: Did you try this with /text() at the end of your query?

Comment: as in `$doc->xpath('A/B[@type="source"]/C/D/E[@ref="description"]/text()');` or `$doc->xpath('A/B[@type="source"]/C/D/E[@ref="description"]')->text();`? Neither produce different results.

Comment: Add a // at the start of your query. //A/B[@type="source"]/C/D/E[@ref="description"] works

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML you provided, the following code will print out the string value of E:

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('URL.xml', null, true);
$path = $doc->xpath('/A/B[@type="source"]/C/D/E[@ref="description"]');
echo $path[0];
```

You need to start your query off with a / to specify the document root.

You can also just query //E[@ref="description"] to find all E elements you want.